# Waiting alert in swift

Tags: ios, alert, message

Xcode 6, single view controller, swift

I am making a game like tic tac toe, and I was wondering how to put in a pop up/alert that says "Waiting for player to make next move" and it has the little spinning loader under it, and then when the player makes the move the message goes away on the player that was waiting and the message pops up on the other player waiting.  Thank you for looking at this and helping.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD). It is an open source library that best suits your need.

Provide your desired message. that will come below spinning wheel.

```
let loadingNotification = MBProgressHUD.showHUDAddedTo(self.view, animated: true)
loadingNotification.mode = MBProgressHUDMode.Indeterminate
loadingNotification.labelText = "Waiting for player to make next move"

//and to dismiss it : 
MBProgressHUD.hideAllHUDsForView(self.view, animated: true)
```

**Update,** **How to do it(bridging and all):**

Steps

1. Drag and drop `MBProgressHUD.h and .m` into your project.
2. It will automatically ask for `bridging` say `NO` *(since we are gonna do it manually).*
3. Add a new file ( a header file .h only) by name `Bridge.h`
4. Type `#import "MBProgressHUD.h"` in newly created file i.e. Bridge.h
5. Go to your project targets and select the top item (that is shown by your project name).
6. Go to `build settings` and make sure `all` is selected.
7. In search box(top left) type `swift compiler`.
8. Change the value of `Objective-C Bridging Header` and put your (`Bridge.h`)file name in there.

Now do stuffs in your Swift file :)

Comment: When I try to put in MBProgressHUD it shows up as an error and says "Use of unresolved identifier 'MBProgressHUD'

Comment: Since you are in Swift and it is in objective-c. use bridging.

Comment: How do I do bridging?  Sorry I've only used swift and only learned a little bit of Objective-c

Comment: Not a point of worry. Bridging doesn't prerequisite obj-c.   M updating my answer.

Comment: if this answer satisfies your query kindly accept the answer

Comment: I got it to work, I had to download the MBProgressHUD files and import them into Xcode.  Thank you for helping.